# DefaultAppPool Identity Account in IIS6

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, application-pools

I need to create a User account that is A) not within the IIS_WPG Group that will write to folders, and B) is used as the DefaultAppPool Identity Account. The purpose of B is because of preventing anonymous HTTP file pushes from Server 1 to Server 2.

I am successful in creating a user account that is set to the AppPool but service only works if it's associated to IIS_WPG. Is there another type of account I can create?

Comment: Is this for an ASP.NET application? Can you tell us more about what you're doing?

Comment: That question really didn't seem straightforward. "Not within the IIS_WPG Group that will write to folders" - the IIS_WPG Group will write to folders, or the user account must not be in that group, and it will write to folders? Why can't it be in IIS_WPG? Why shouldn't it? What mechanism are you using to write to the folders? WebDAV (Write permission in IIS Manager? An upload page/control/form posting?)

Answer (score 0):

You *can't not* have a pool identity that isn't a member of `IIS_WPG` *and* be an application pool identity. The `IIS_WPG` group is configured with just the right amount of NTFS permissions and user privileges to allow members of the group to be application pool identities.

See: [IIS and Built-in Accounts (IIS 6.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true) and in particular: [Configuring Application Pool Identity in IIS 6.0 (IIS 6.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/12a3d96c-65ea-4210-96ad-86a801f6a88c.mspx?mfr=true)

If you wanted to set up another group or user with the same minimum permission set it would be identical to what `IIS_WPG` has.

One thing you shouldn't be doing is assigning the `IIS_WPG` group any kind of permission in your web folders. `IIS_WPG` is just a convenient group to allow admins to permit custom user accounts to be pool identities.

The rights you should be assigning to your IIS web folders should be the pool account itself where the pool account is also the anonymous user for the site.

Or, if you're running multiple sites inside the same pool but need different anonymous identities then you would configure additional windows accounts and set these as the anonymous user.

Comment: We are using Adobe CQ for our content management. Server B publishes files to Server A when a browser request comes in via HTTP. But that request is anonymous on Server A, hence why I cannot use the default account in the DefaultPoolApp. We won't want just anybody be able to push files to our web server.

The issue with not using IIS_WPG is because our server admins do not want write permissions granted for this Group, so I need to have another group, assumingly, with the same minimal permissions.